# What's the notation for a function restricted to a subset of the codomain?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, notation, mathematical-writing

Suppose I have a function f : A → B between two sets A and B. (The same question applies to group homomorphisms, continuous maps between topological spaces, etc. But for simpicity let's restrict ourselves to the case of arbitrary maps between sets.)

If I have subset A' ⊆ A of the domain A, then I can **restrict** f to A'. There is the function f|<sub>A'</sub> : A' → B which is given by f|<sub>A'</sub>(a) = f(a) for all a ∈ A'.

Suppose now that I have subset B' ⊆ B of the codomain B that contains the image of the map f. Similarly I can **restrict** f to B', meaning that there is a function g : A → B' which is given by g(a) = f(a) for all a ∈ A.

In general, it might be useful to consider such functions g and have a name for them, for example if I have a function B' → C that I want to apply afterwards. Unfortunately, I haven't seen a name or symbol for this function g in literature.

> Is there notation for the
>   restriction g of f to a subset of the
>   codomain similar to the notation
>   f|<sub>A'</sub> for a restriction to a
>   subset of the domain?

Comment: What's wrong with $f|_{f^{-1}(B')}$?

Comment: @Willie Wong:  the target of your function is still $B$.

@noname:  Let $\iota: B'\to B$ be the inclusion; then the function you are referring to is sometimes called $\iota^*f$, which as the notation suggests is a special case of the pullback.

Comment: I'd be tempted to invent the notation ${}_{B'}|f$ for this.

Comment: According to the usual convention that a function is just a special kind of relation, two functions agree if they have the same domain and act the same way on it. So the answer by Willie Wong is perfectly fine.

Comment: Is the inclusion map {0}->{0,1} the same as the identity map {0}->{0}? According to one well-established "usual convention", they are, since a function is a set of ordered pairs. According to another, they are not. You need the latter convention in order to meaningfully ask questions like "is this function surjective?"  

Comment: I like the name corestriction and I would adopt Harald's excellent notation for it.

Comment: @Tom: thanks for the clarification. Now I understand the question. In the case that $f(A) \subset B'$, I like the pull-back notation better. But I think Harald's notation probably deals more succintly with the case where that assumption is not true. 

Comment: One other thought: perhaps someone should dig into the multi-function literature to see whether they have an established notation? It seems to be something that they are likely to run into more often. 

Comment: @Harald: Alternatively, for ease of typesetting: $f|^{B'}$.  

Comment: I find yours is nicer. I've never liked back-stuff such as $^tA$ or $_3 F_2$. 

Comment: I think the honest answer is that most mathematicians simply call the function "$f$". That is, although according to the agreed upon set-theoretic definition for a function, we should regard two functions as different if they have different codomains (each containing the image of the function), in practice this is rarely done. For instance, it feels a little stuffy to distinguish between the function $f:x \mapsto x^2$ as a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$  and the same (!) mapping viewed as a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$. 

Comment: Yes, but the original poster is obviously in a situation where it matters.

Comment: Pete, you are right about the stuffiness, but we have to acknowledge that your first function is not surjective whereas your second is, so in that respect we should consider them different.

Comment: In a category theory centric setting, of course the codomain matters. Many working mathematicians, myself included, hardly ever need the concept, and we have no problem with the word “surjective” requiring some context to be precise. (If precision is needed, we can ask “does $f$ map $X$ onto $Y$?” rather than “is $f$ surjective”?) But it seems a mistake to assume that just because some of us can live without caring about codomains, nobody needs them.

Comment: @Harald: I didn't say (and I don't believe) that no one needs the concept of a codomain.  I was just offering my opinion as to why there is not a standard notation for "astriction".  My point was that a lot of times the restriction of the codomain goes without saying.  If someone asked you what the inverse function of $x^2$ is, I imagine you would say $\sqrt{x}$ and not "Hold on, what's the codomain?  If it's $\mathbb{R}$, then no inverse function exists"?  Again, none of this is my own advice on how things should be done; I'm just reporting the way I think things are.

Comment: @Pete: Fair enough.

Comment: Daniel Litt's proposed notation `$i^*f$` (where $i$ is the inclusion of $B'$ into $B$) correctly indicates that this is a pullback, but it may cause a problem in the case of smooth maps between manifolds.  There, one usually uses the "star" notation for pulling back differential forms (along a map from the new domain into the original domain), and one wants this notation even for 0-forms, i.e., for functions (e.g., to say that $d$ commutes with pulling back).  

Answer (score 15):

Concerning the name for the notion in question, but not the notation, Exposé 2 by A. Andreotti in the Séminaire A. Grothendieck 1957, available at www.numdam.org, suggests the following:

Consider a morphism $f:A\rightarrow B$ in some category, subobjects $i:U\rightarrow A$ and $j:V\rightarrow B$ of $A$ and $B$, respectively, and quotient objects $p:A\rightarrow P$ and $q:B\rightarrow Q$ of $A$ and $B$, respectively.

Then, $f\circ i$ is *the restriction of $f$ to $U$.* Dually, $q\circ f$ is *the corestriction of $f$ to $Q$.* (In particular, with the usual usage of the prefix "co", corestriction is not suitable for the notion in question.)

Moreover, if there is a morphism $g:P\rightarrow B$ with $g\circ p=f$, then $g$ is *the astriction of $f$ to $P$.* Dually, if there is a morphism $h:A\rightarrow V$ with $j\circ h=f$, then $h$ is *the coastriction of $f$ to $V$.* (Of course one can argue whether one should swap the terms astriction and coastriction (as suggested by Gerald Edgar).)

Comment: The relevant exposé: [Andreotti - Généralités sur les catégories abéliennes (suite)](http://www.numdam.org/item/SG_1957__1__A2_0/).

Answer (score 13):

I would call it simply a pullback (along $B'$). Thus, you may denote it by $f \times_B B'$.

If we pullback a map $f : A \to B$ along a subset $B' \subseteq B$, we get the map $f^{-1}(B') \to B', x \mapsto f(x)$. If the image of $f$ happens to be a subset of $B'$, then $f^{-1}(B')=A$.

Comment: I agree. This is the most sensible thing to do.

Comment: I agree with this (and Daniel Litt's comment).

Comment: I think the preimage (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Preimage.html) notation $f^{-1}(B')$ is very sensible, and therefore I would denote the restricted function with ${f}|_{f^{-1}(B')}$

Answer (score 12):

If I wanted a name, I might use "corestriction."

Answer (score 5):

It's called a range restriction.  There's no established notation, but you might as well use the Z notation which is *f*  ▷ B'. (`f \rhd B'` in LaTeX plus amsfonts)

Answer (score 3):

The terminology I have seen for this is "astriction".

Comment: Well, yet another example that not all existing terminology should be perpetuated! :) 



Answer (score 3):

Here's some notation.

Given a morphism $f : A \rightarrow B$ and a subobject $b': B' \rightarrow B$, the astriction of $f$ to $B' \subseteq B$ can be denoted $b'\backslash\, f : A \rightarrow B'$, pronounced "$b'$ under $f$." It satisfies $b'\circ (b'\backslash\, f).$ For example, if we have a function $f : A \rightarrow B$ and subsets $X$ of $A$ and $Y$ of $B$ such that $f(X)\subseteq Y$, then the relevant map $X \rightarrow Y$ can be denoted $Y\,\backslash\, (f \circ X).$

Similar notation can be used in linear algebra to denote solution sets. For example; to denote the set of all vectors $x$ satisfying a linear equation $Ax=b,$ I tend to write $A \backslash b.$ This has an intuitive look about it: $$Ax = b \iff x \in A \backslash b.$$

The connection basically is that in the category of matrices, $Ax=b$ can be seen as a factorization of $b$ through the tail of $A$ (because $A$ is on the left). So, the general principle is that:

> In any category, $g \backslash \,f$ is good notation for the set of all factorizations of $f$ through the tail of $g$, or for the unique such factorization just in case a unique factorization exists.

Dually, if we have a function $f : A \rightarrow B$ and a quotient object $a' : A \rightarrow A'$, we can write $f/a'$ for the relevant morphism $A' \rightarrow B$ when it exists, or else use this notation to denote the set of all such morphisms.

Comment: maarten fokkinga carries this division-notation to arbitrary colimits; see his lovely monograph here: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4204/cd13e420923b4f6f845ef00e3085aeeeaad3.pdf

Answer (score 2):

This would fit as a response to Harald Hanche-Olsen's remark, but I have not enough points for this.

Anyway, Mizar mathematial library chose exactly this notation; actually, it is introduced in the article on basic relations [RELAT_1.MIZ](http://mizar.org/JFM/pdf/relat_1.pdf), Def. 12, so it fits any relation and any set.

In a Mizar article you have just ASCII, so no subscripts, but you can always avoid ambiguities like f|X versus X|f by typing the two objects appearing in the notation as Relation and set respectively. I find interesting that what is expressible on paper by varying font size is emulated by typing in a proof checker.